# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at com.mysamples.jsonparsingdemo2.MainActivity$MovieAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:158)

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I am trying to parse the json object but still the error appears.
  here is the code from the MainActivity.java:
The error states.

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.mysamples.jsonparsingdemo2, PID: 2618
                                                                              java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

```
package com.mysamples.jsonparsingdemo2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mysamples.jsonparsingdemo2.models.MovieModels;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        }




public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,List<MovieModels>> {

    @Override
    protected List<MovieModels> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            InputStream stream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
                sBuffer.append(line);
            }

            //Organizing the JSON object the JSON OBJECT
            String finalJson = sBuffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("movies");

            //getting the objects from the url
            List<MovieModels> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j <parentArray.length() ; j++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(j);
                MovieModels models = new MovieModels();


                //Displaying the values from the url
                models.setMovie(finalObject.getString("movie"));
                models.setYear(finalObject.getInt("year"));
                models.setRating((float) finalObject.getDouble("rating"));
                models.setDirector(finalObject.getString("director"));
                models.setDuration(finalObject.getString("duration"));
                models.setTagline(finalObject.getString("tagline"));
                models.setImage(finalObject.getString("image"));
                models.setStory(finalObject.getString("story"));


                //getting the values from castList
                List<MovieModels.Cast> castList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i <finalObject.getJSONArray("cast").length() ; i++) {
                    MovieModels.Cast cast = new MovieModels.Cast();
                    cast.setName(finalObject.getJSONArray("cast").getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                    castList.add(cast);
                }
                models.setCastList(castList);
                modelList.add(models);
            }

            return modelList;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            if (httpURLConnection!=null){
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader!= null){
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<MovieModels> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        MovieAdapter movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_row, result);
        listView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
    }
}

public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    private List<MovieModels> modelList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public MovieAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<MovieModels> objects) {
        super(context, resource,  objects);
        modelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView != null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,null);
        }

        //CASTING ALL THE VIEWS FROM THE CUSTOM_ROW LAYOUT
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textViewMovie;
        TextView textViewYear;
        TextView textViewDuration;
        TextView textViewDirector;
        TextView textViewTagLine;
        TextView textViewCast;
        TextView textViewStory;
        RatingBar ratingBar;

        imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textViewMovie = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMovie);
        textViewYear = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewYear);
        textViewDuration =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDuration);
        textViewDirector = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDirector);
        textViewTagLine = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTagLine);
        textViewCast = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCast);
        textViewStory = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStory);
        ratingBar = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarMovie);


        //DISPLAYING THE TEXT TO THE TEXTVIEWS
        textViewMovie.setText(modelList.get(position).getMovie());
        textViewYear.setText(String.valueOf(modelList.get(position).getYear()));
        textViewDuration.setText(modelList.get(position).getDuration());
        textViewDirector.setText(modelList.get(position).getDirector());
        textViewTagLine.setText(modelList.get(position).getTagline());

        //RATINGBAR
        ratingBar.setRating(modelList.get(position).getRating()/2);

        //GETTING THE CAST NAME FROM THE ARRAY
        StringBuffer castBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (MovieModels.Cast cast : modelList.get(position).getCastList()){
            castBuffer.append(cast.getName()+ ", ");
        }
        textViewCast.setText(castBuffer);
        textViewStory.setText(modelList.get(position).getStory());

        return convertView;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        new JSONTask().execute("http://jsonparsing.parseapp.com/jsonData/moviesData.txt");
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: YOu ran out of memory,  Use less and check for leaks.  Biggest likelihood is your image, if you're loading them all into memory you'll die quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this wrong condition in the if statement (convertView != null) to (converView == null)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So , first change your JSON to this below , for simplicity me i dont use Urls in my JSON , I just write the exact Image name.

```
{
      "movie": "Interstellar",
      "year": 2014,
      "rating": 8.7,
      "duration": "169 min",
      "director": "Christopher Nolan",
      "tagline": "Mankind was born on Earth. It was never meant to die here.",
      "cast": [
        {
          "name": "Matthew McConaughey"
        },
        {
          "name": "Anne Hathaway"
        },
        {
          "name": "Jessica Chastain"
        },
        {
          "name": "Wes Bentley"
        }
      ],
      "image": "interstellar.jpg",
      "story": "A team of explorers travel through a wormhole in space in an attempt to ensure humanity's survival."
    },
    {
      "movie": "Fantastic Four",
      "year": 2015,
      "rating": 4.0,
      "duration": "100 min",
      "director": "Josh Trank",
      "tagline": "Change is coming.",
      "cast": [
        {
          "name": "Miles Teller"
        },
        {
          "name": "Kate Mara"
        },
        {
          "name": "Michael B. Jordan"
        }
      ],
      "image": "four.jpg",
      "story": "Four young outsiders teleport to an alternate and dangerous universe which alters their physical form in shocking ways. The four must learn to harness their new abilities and work together to save Earth from a former friend turned enemy."
    }
```

Then go in your Adapter class and first declare this;

```
private String url_load_images="http://jsonparsing.parseapp.com/jsonData/images/";
```

then afterwards go `getView()` method and modify it as below.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView != null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,null);
        }

        //CASTING ALL THE VIEWS FROM THE CUSTOM_ROW LAYOUT
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textViewMovie;
        TextView textViewYear;
        TextView textViewDuration;
        TextView textViewDirector;
        TextView textViewTagLine;
        TextView textViewCast;
        TextView textViewStory;
        RatingBar ratingBar;

        imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textViewMovie = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMovie);
        textViewYear = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewYear);
        textViewDuration =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDuration);
        textViewDirector = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDirector);
        textViewTagLine = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTagLine);
        textViewCast = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCast);
        textViewStory = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStory);
        ratingBar = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarMovie);


        //DISPLAYING THE TEXT TO THE TEXTVIEWS
        textViewMovie.setText(modelList.get(position).getMovie());
        textViewYear.setText(String.valueOf(modelList.get(position).getYear()));
        textViewDuration.setText(modelList.get(position).getDuration());
        textViewDirector.setText(modelList.get(position).getDirector());
        textViewTagLine.setText(modelList.get(position).getTagline());

        //RATINGBAR
        ratingBar.setRating(modelList.get(position).getRating()/2);

        //GETTING THE CAST NAME FROM THE ARRAY
        StringBuffer castBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (MovieModels.Cast cast : modelList.get(position).getCastList()){
            castBuffer.append(cast.getName()+ ", ");
        }
        textViewCast.setText(castBuffer);
        textViewStory.setText(modelList.get(position).getStory());



final MovieModels models = modelList.get(position);
    Picasso.with(context)
        .load(url_load_images+models.getImage)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
        .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
        .into(imageView);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to change the image and resize it but stil the error appears like this:
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.mysamples.jsonparsingdemo2.MainActivity$MovieAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:172):  this line imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

Comment: How did you resize your images have you used picasso or Glide @GabeSechan. Please tell ASAP

Comment: Now what you are gonna do @BobCastro, google about a library called `picasso`, this library handles Image caching http://square.github.io/picasso/, add its dependency in the gradle file or it's lib in the lib folder. Photoshop won't solve that issue @BobCastro. Tell me where you've reached, so far

Comment: But you didn't post your model class

Comment: i change the 'if (convertView !=null) to if(convertView == null)

Comment: first do what I posted and you see,  the outcome.

Comment: If it works tell me @Bob , but don't change `if(convertView !=null) to if(convertView == null)`

Comment: i couldn't change the JSOn cause it's not my JSON Object. I don't own that link though.

Comment: Ooooh gosh , is it ahomework, it would have been better if you change

Comment: I just watched a tutorial in youtube. then, I was having an error. So I decided to post it here. And by the way, Thanks for your help man.!